# Arrow before folders when you enable expandability in the list view, to be visible only if subfolders or files are present in the parent folder

Tags: 22.04, nautilus, filemanager

In Ubuntu 22.04 Nautilus > Preferences you have "Expandable Folders in List View"

[image]

**If you activate the "Tree" option, the arrow in front of the folders will be present even for empty folders:**

[image]

The arrow should only be present before folders when the parent directory is not empty, but it is always present, which causes a lot of confusion. What's the trick to expanding an empty folder?

I use Nemo as File Manager on another laptop and the arrow before the folder is only present if that folder is not empty. Which also makes sense!

Can this be considered a fault (bug)?

**Question:**
How can I make Nautilus show the arrow in front of folders only if the parent folder is not empty?

Comment: I guess that is not possible and you should ask the developers, if they can implement such function.

Comment: Yes, this is a bug which cannot be altered by the end user. You can report it either against the `nautilus` package on [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus) or in the [project's GitLab](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus).

Comment: Report bug at gnome via GitLab is not possible because whoever was setting the gnome account permissions on GitLab didn't make the right settings. Doesn't allow registration or login through GitLab or GitHub, gets error 422 "Sign-in failed because Email is not allowed for sign-up. Please use your regular email address. Check with your administrator". Doesn't gnome wonder why they have so few bug reports? :)

Comment: Strange... I can properly connect with my GitHub account and I'm able to post bug reports... I can also see about 10 bug reports being posted the last week only.

Comment: BTW, when replying  to a user with a comment, ping them by using @ followed by the user's username (e.g. @Marius), so they will be notified about your comment. I was only able to see that you commented because I follow your post, but most users don't do that, so unless they revisit your post, they would have no other way of knowing that you responded. ;)

Comment: @BeastOfCaerbannog A topic has been created on the Gnome forum where there is a screenshot of the error that makes it impossible to register on Gnome GitLab to submit a bug. https://discourse.gnome.org/t/register-to-report-a-bug-via-gitlab-error-422/14018

Comment: UPDATE 2023-02-21
Bug reported here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/2007998